# get id from row custom attribute

Tags: jquery

How I can get id out of custom attribute?

My row tag has custom attribute:

```
<tr data-type="element" data-id="<?php echo $item->id; ?>">
```

My jquery code:

```
// Delete Item
$('a[name=c5]').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var t = $(this);
    
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?') == true) {
        var id = t.parent().parent().children('td').children('input[type=checkbox]').val(); // I cant use this anymore because I dont use checkboxes any more. Just delete button.
        var element = t.parent().parent();
        var height = element.height();
        
        $.post('rent.php', {
            'act':'2',
            'id':id
        }, function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            if(data == '1')
                element.fadeOut(700);
            else
                alert('Something went wrong. Please try again');
        });
    }
});
```

I want add to row attribute item ID so my delete button knows it is this item to delete from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `a` element you click on is within the `tr` with the `data` attribute, then you can use a combination of `closest()` and `data()`:

```
var id = t.closest('tr').data('id');
```